# How do I declare a DefaultValue attribute whose value is an array of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, default-value

I've been using the DefaultValue attribute in a code generator which writes a C# class definition from a schema.

I'm stuck where a property in the schema is an array of strings.

I'd like to write something like this in my C#:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(string[]), ["a","b"])]
public string[] Names{get;set;}
```

but that won't compile.

Is there any way I can successfully declare the default value attribute for a string array?

Comment: `["a","b"]` is not valid syntax. `new[] { "a", "b" }` is.

Comment: @Jon: In fact, `new[] { "a", "b" }` is not valid C# syntax either, or is it? I mean, without an element type of the array?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: [Implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx).

Comment: @Jon: Interesting new feature :-) We aren't yet using .NET 4.5 (in fact, most of our projects are still stuck in the 3.5 toolset), so I hadn't yet encountered this.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Not quite new, it's been there since C# 3.0.

Comment: @Jon: Fascinating. I wonder why I've never seen it used anywhere. Thanks for point me to it :-)

Comment: That doesn't work in the attribute since the second parameter has to be a string.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If you were using Resharper, you'd long known about it because not only does it save you from introducing lots of subtle bugs by creating warnings (made possible due to statically analyzing your code and flow quite deeply), but it displays redundancies, like the explicit type in this case, [grayed out](http://www.neevtech.com/blog/2013/06/21/thank-youresharper/) for you to notice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try

```
[DefaultValue(new string[] { "a", "b" })]
```

As you want to pass a new string array, you have to instantiate it - that's done by `new string[]`. C# allows an initialization list with the initial contents of the array to follow in braces, i.e. `{ "a", "b" }`.

---

EDIT: As correctly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478837/how-do-i-declare-a-defaultvalue-attribute-whose-value-is-an-array-of-strings/12478891#comment121083184_12478891) by [Cory-G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1884803/cory-g), you may want to make sure your actual instances do not receive the very array instance stored in the `DefaultValue` attribute. Otherwise, changes to that instance might influence default values across your application.

Instead, you could use your property's setter to copy the assigned array.

Comment: @MichaelBishop: Your comment on the question implies you are using `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute`? (That wasn't clear in the question; from the question, I assumed it's some other thusly named attribute type that offers a `(Type, object)` constructor.) If so, you could try and use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx2at1a8.aspx) and not pass any `Type`.

Comment: [DefaultValue(new string[] { "a", "b" })]
This works. Thank you! I saw all the DefaultValueAttribute constructors for specific types and didn't even realize I could pass a generic object.

Comment: How would you do this with generic list? Like this as default value `new List<CommonModels.Contact>`

Comment: @DonnyV.: I am not sure that is possible.

Comment: I come across this answer while looking for a more generic syntax. This does not appear to work with custom class/struct definitions e.g. `[DefaultValue(new Whatever[] {})]` (I wanted empty array default)

Comment: This solution seems potentially dangerous for the unaware. Pretty sure this will return a shared reference, meaning that if you alter the array at all, then the default held by the attribute along with all that got this value will be changed. If using this, maybe put a bit of "copy array" code in your setter or something.

Comment: @Cory-G: True; I've edited it in. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to take advantage of the virtual nature of `DefaultValueAttribute` and derive your own. Below are some examples with non-constant-able types.

#### Example Usage:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    [DefaultValueNew( typeof(List<int>), new int[]{2,2} )]
    public List<int> SomeList { get; set; }

    // -- Or --
    public static List<int> GetDefaultSomeList2() => new List<int>{2,2};

    [DefaultValueCallStatic( typeof(Foo), nameof(GetDefaultSomeList2) )]
    public List<int> SomeList2 { get; set; }
};
```

#### Here are the definitions of those attributes:

```cs
  public class DefaultValueNewAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
  {
    public Type Type { get; }
    public object[] Args { get; }

    public DefaultValueNewAttribute(Type type, params object[] args)
      : base(null)
    {
      Type = type;
      Args = args;
    }

    public override object? Value => Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Args);
  };

  public class DefaultValueCallStaticAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
  {
    public Type Type { get; }
    public string Method { get; }

    public DefaultValueCallStaticAttribute(Type type, string method)
      : base(null)
    {
      Type = type;
      Method = method;
    }

    public override object? Value => Type.GetMethod(Method, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null);
  };
```

### Gotchas to be aware of

Be careful when defining your own `DefaultValueAttribute`. Most importantly, learn a bit about how it will get used before creating it. For something like a code generator, the above is likely ok. If, however, you are using it with Newtonsoft Json or something that will mostly only use it to compare values, then you may want the value within to be more constant, in order to save time and not re-create the object every time.

For a situation where you want the value to not be re-created every time, you may do something more like:

```cs
  public static readonly List<int> DefaultAges = new List<int>{2,2};
  private List<int> __ages = new List<int>(DefaultAges);
  [DefaultValueStatic( typeof(List<int>), nameof(DefaultAges) )]
  public List<int> Ages { get => __ages; set {__ages = new List<int>(value);}
```

Where the attribute `DefaultValueStatic` is defined as:

```cs
  public class DefaultValueStaticAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
  {
    public DefaultValueStaticAttribute(Type type, string memberName) : base(null)
    {
      foreach (var member in type.GetMember( memberName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public ))
      {
        if (member is FieldInfo fi) { SetValue(fi.GetValue(type)); return; }
        if (member is PropertyInfo pi) { SetValue(pi.GetValue(type)); return; }
      }
      throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to get static member '{memberName}' from type '{type.Name}'");
    }
  };
```

The above version will ensure that the default value is not re-created. This can be useful with something like Newtonsoft json, where the setters won't be called often, but the default comparison will.

Again, just make sure you know a bit of how the attribute will be used.